# Button in top corner of my page?

Tags: css, html, input

I have a random button (input) in the top left corner of my page, can you tell me how to fix this?!

Here is a picture: http://d.pr/h8An

Here is my code:

```
        <img class="iphone" src="img/iphone.png" />
        <img class="sp_title" src="img/sp_title.png" />
        <img class="sp_detail" src="img/sp_detail.png" />
        <img class="sp_emailText" src="img/emailtext.png" />    
        <img class="sp_emailField" src="img/sp_emailField.png" />
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="emailField" placeholder="" name="email" />
            <button type="submit">
                 <div class="submit" />
            </button>
        </form> 
</body>

.iphone {
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    position: absolute;
}
.sp_title {
    top:150px;
    right: 350px;
    position: absolute;
}
.sp_detail {
    top: 250px;
    right: 275px;
    position: absolute;
}
.sp_emailText {
    top:350px;
    right:295px;
    position: absolute;
}
.sp_emailField {
    top:400px;
    right:275px;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url("../img/sp_emailField.png");
}
.emailField {
    top:413px;
    right:290px;
    width: 355px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    font-size: 17;
    text-align: center;
    color: #AE5532;
}
.submit {
    bottom: 100px;
    right: 400px; 
    width: 135px;
    height: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("../img/submitBtn.png");
}
.submit:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/submitBtnhover.png");
}
.return {
    top: 465px;
    right: 365px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That button is in your code.

```
<button type="submit">
     <div class="submit" />
</button>
```

So it really isn't random at all.

If you don't want it there, remove it from your code.

EDIT: If you're talking about the *positioning* of that element, it's because you're changing the position of the `<div>` instead of the `<button>`.  If your browser's debugging tools support it, inspect the `<div>` and you'll see it's positioned correctly.  Remember, when you specify an absolute position for an element, you're removing that element from the document flow, just like with floats.  Parent elements will *not* resize or move to accommodate it for you.

Comment: How can I submit the button then and retain the div background-image class?

Comment: @XcodeDev If I understand you correctly, you can replace it with `<input type = "image" src = "foo.jpg">`.

Comment: My problem with that is that there is no hover enabled, if I can get a hover image to show up, then that would be a great solution

Comment: @XcodeDev Well, you could always try specifying an absolute position for the `<button>`.  If that doesn't work, you might be SOL.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing absolute positioning and static positioning is quite tricky, because absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow - [this webpage](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) gives an understandable overview with examples of the different positioning methods and their impact - effects and side effects.

Without seeing the big picture of what you need it's not easy to give the right solution, but probably the easiest way to solve the problem - assuming there's no solution to get rid of the absolute positioning - is to wrap the form in a div that's absolutely positioned, and completely avoid statically positioned elements on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the button position to absolute and dock it to the top, like this:

```
input[type="button"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

There you have it .. Hope this helps !